# Breaking a python string in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, substring

I have a column 'released' which has values like 'June 13, 1980 (United States)'

I want to get the year from this string so I tried using the following code

```
df['year_correct'] = df['released'].astype(str).str[',':'(']
```

But it is returning all the values as Nan in the new 'year_correct' column. Please help

Comment: Are the country names always in parenthesis? You could split on that first: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html

Comment: If the year comes always after comma and space than you can do something like this  `split(",")[1][1:5]`. You split by comma, than you get the year from position 1 to 5.

Comment: Yes they are always in parenthesis, but I don't need country name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better way might be to extract the 4 digits value using words delimiter (`\b`) to ensure no more than 4 digits:

```
df['year_correct'] = df['released'].astype(str).str.extract(r'\b(\d{4})\b')
```

Example:

```
                        released year_correct
0  June 13, 1980 (United States)         1980
```